# Samsung Galaxy S4, screen flickers on animation

Tags: android, android-animation, samsung-mobile, flicker

My application uses animations, frequently one screen has two or more animations or transitions running, using `ImageSwitchers` / `TextSwitchers` / or custom `LayerAnimators`.

I have tested the application in many different devices: Samsung Galaxy Tabs & Notes (ICS / JB), LG tablets (Android Kitkat 4.4.0), Amazon Kindle Fire HDX (Android JB fork), as well as on the Genymotion Emulator for Android versions from 4.2 to 4.4.

However, on the Samsung Galaxy S4 phone -Android KitKat 4.4.4-, in theory a powerhorse that outperforms all the rest, I see very frequent screen flickering. They only happen when animations are running, so they are apparently a side effect. The rest of devices don't ever show such a problem.

I'd appreciate any thoughts. Do you have a similar experience with this phone? Is it something I have to worry about?

Note: All Kiktats are running Dalvik runtime. Switching to ART produces the same results (Samsung flickers, the rest don't)

Comment: Screen flickering might also mean that the Application Not Responding (ANR) option has been enabled in your Samsung S4's settings?

Comment: If it's turned off, then it's not ANR. You might have to post your codes that perform the animation so we can help you.

Comment: I tend to test Android development on stock / AOSP ROMs first just to ensure no unforseen problems. Once you're happy, then proceed to custom ROMs (CyanogenMod, etc).

Comment: @ChuongPham it was the custom rom! On a stock(ish) ROM it works nicely as expeted! thx!

Comment: Please don't mark subjects as solved, or put answers in questions; create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy S4 was using a highly customized Firmware & Kernel "SlimSaberKat" that caused all this. Reverting to a stockish Firmware caused everything to run smoothly and without flickering, as expected.

Specifically, the kernel enabled a special advanced rendering mode that the phone does not yet fully support. Those modes are setup in the `build.prop` file in the root of the system partition, and are related to the very lowlevel details of the graphics pipeline. Unfortunately, the only HW accelerated mode that works flawlessly in this phone is he simplest one "`gpu`". There are 2 other modes that additionally support Full Hardware Composition, namely C2D and [i can't remember]. Those modes cause flickering on this phone but are supposed to greatly ease the load of the CPU.

I ended up installing CyanoGenMod v11.0, a version specifically tuned for the S4, and all my problems disappeared.